# Unable to deploy pods on GKE cluster created using 'Ubuntu with Docker' image

Tags: docker, image, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy few pods on GKE cluster created using image "Ubuntu with docker" and they are giving the error below. I did not find any solution on the internet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: invalid mount {Destination:[/sys/fs/cgroup Type:bind Source:/var/lib/docker/volumes/d9e3b871f4cc210e3dba6471f326dcbf7b404daad7906ed9fc669e207c093ec2/_data Options:[rbind]}: mount destination [/sys/fs/cgroup not absolute: unknown
```

### The spec file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  labels:
    diamanti.com/app: armada
    diamanti.com/control-plane: 'true'
  name: armada
  namespace: diamanti-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      diamanti.com/app: armada
      diamanti.com/control-plane: 'true'
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ''
      labels:
        diamanti.com/app: armada
        diamanti.com/control-plane: 'true'
    spec:
      containers:
        - envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: armada-config
          image: 'diamanti/armada:v3.3.1-197'
          name: armada
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      nodeSelector:
        spektra.diamanti.io/node: "true"
      hostNetwork: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      serviceAccount: diamanti-node-runner
      serviceAccountName: diamanti-node-runner
      tolerations:
        - effect: NoSchedule
          key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
```

The serviceaccount diamanti-node-runner is bound to cluster-admin role.

Comment: better to post the deploy manifest

Comment: Added a spec file.

Answer (score 0):

As Kubernetes is removing the support for docker runtime you can use the other container runtime. Use their default, it works fine. You do not need to change anything at your end related to docker images.

[image: GCE containerd]

Comment: Thanks Karan but this OS does not allow to create files on the node as the file system is read only. 

..
spec: failed to generate spec: failed to mkdir "/sbin/nvme": mkdir /sbin/nvme: read-only file system

Comment: @sandeep You should write these details in your question if you expect the Stack Overflow community to help you resolve it.

Comment: Can you try changing the path of data where you are trying to write. According to me whole OS cannot be read only, there are some directories where you cannot write. Please let me know if that works.

Comment: I tried installing K8s with GCP VM instances running Ubuntu 20.04 and containerd 1.4.13/16.7 and its working fine on this setup but it is not working on GKE created K8s cluster where I selected Ubuntu(20.04 default) with containerd(1.5.2 default). With Ubuntu and containerd I get the same error
-----------------------------------------
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: invalid mount {Destination:[/sys/fs/cgroup Type:bind ....
... mount destination [/sys/fs/cgroup not absolute: unknown

Comment: The Dockerfile of the image I am using has an entry for volume like this 

VOLUME [[/sys/fs/cgroup /run]]

Surprisingly its working on K8s created by me on GCP VM instances running Ubuntu and containerd and its not working on K8s create by GKE which also has Ubuntu and containerd